# Bourne shell scripts with user input

Tags: unix, sh

I'm trying to teach myself the basics of Bourne shell scripting using a textbook I borrowed from the library, and I'm working through the questions at the end of each chapter. However, I just got to one and I'm stumped...

> Write a script that takes zero or more arguments and prints the last argument in the list. For example, given the argument 'myProgram arg1 arg2 arg3', the output would be 'arg3'.

Could anyone give me some advice on how to set this one up? I'm trying to review the section on user input and arguments, but I haven't worked with that much so far, so I don't have much practice yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo ${!#}         # bash only
eval echo \${$#}   # sh-compatible
```

#### Explanation

The number of arguments is `$#`. Variables can be accessed indirectly via `${!VAR}`. For example:

```
$ VAR="PATH"
$ echo ${!VAR}
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Put those together and if we have a variable `$n` containing an integer we can access the `$n`th command-line argument with `${!n}`. Or instead of `$n` let's use `$#`; the last command-line argument is `${!#}`!

---

Additionally, this can be more longwindedly written using array slicing (`$@` is an array holding all the command-line arguments) as:

```
echo ${@:$#:$#}
```

Oddly, you cannot use an array index:

```
# Does not work
echo ${@[$#]}
```

Comment: I may very well be incorrect, but aren't all of those bashisms (except the `$#`)?  I'm not certain they would work with the old-fashioned bourne shell.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I must've missed the section in which the command `$#` is mentioned... it definitely seems useful for this problem! One thing though - what is the purpose of the `!` in your command `${!#}`? I can't find anything about exclamation marks in my book. (Edit: nevermind, I just noticed your explanation upon refreshing!)

Comment: @TimPote Good point. I've added an alternate solution that is sh-compatible.

Comment: I've tried using your sh-compatible code, and I think I've run into a problem. Upon evaluating more than 9 arguments, I receive a strange output (for instance, running `myProgram q w e r t y u i o p` outputs `q0`). Why would this happen? I don't think I made any mistakes in typing the code.

Comment: @user41419 Good catch. To access the 10th argument you can't do `$10` as it's interpreted as `${1}0`. You have to write `${10}`. I've edited my answer to include the curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just give you some pointers.  Since you want to learn bash, you probably don't just want a piece of code that does what the question asks:

1) Do you know how to count how many arguments your bash function has?

2) Do you know how to loop?

3) Do you know how to "pop" one of the arguments?

4) Do you know how to print out the first argument?

If you put all that together, I bet you'll come up with it.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough outline! I suppose understanding is definitely better than just asking for lines of code, but I'm only just starting to learn about arguments, so I'm still pretty new to this. I do know about 1 and 2, and I think I understand 4, but I'll read up on 3 as well before tackling this.

Comment: Look for "shift" on #4.  But, John Kugelman posted a more efficient solution than I had in mind.